# How can I generate valid Source Maps with Gulp, Uglify & Concat?

Tags: javascript, gulp, uglifyjs, source-maps, gulp-uglify

Has anyone found a working combination of Gulp, Uglify and Concat that generates a valid source map? There appears to be lots of issues in GitHub regarding these sorts of interactions, but equally people appear to have found combinations that work successfully. I've tried numerous variations, but the moment I turn on uglify the symbol mapping does not work and breakpoints don't work correctly in the browser. As an example, the following works fine:

```
return gulp.src('/scripts/*.js')
            .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
            //.pipe(uglify())
            .pipe(concat(outputName + '.min.js'))
            .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
            .pipe(gulp.dest(outputPath))
            .on('end', function() { gutil.log('Minified ' + outputName); })
            .on('error', handleError);
```

but uncomment uglify and it doesn't.

I have created a GitHub repo to reproduce the issue: https://github.com/jamescrowley/gulpIssues

Comment: weird... I tried your snippet and it works totally fine... could you add the `package.json`? I find it weird that you have version 2.4.21 of uglify-js, when `gulp-uglify` freezes on 2.4.19.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/jamescrowley/e56e9f591d6a86011f12 - though I may try re-installing them all from fresh. could you confirm what combination worked for you?

Comment: I will try as soon as I'm at my PC again. Try getting rid of `uglify.js` in the meantime. `gulp-uglify` comes with its own `uglify.js` dependency, and maybe they interfer with each other

Comment: @ddprrt I've created a small repo to reproduce the issue - https://github.com/jamescrowley/gulpIssues - if you have any insight I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: @ddprrt btw, I've verified this is an issue on OS x too

Comment: Exact same issue here. Thinking about switching to Webpack...

Answer (score 1):

We've been using it as:

```
.pipe(sourcemaps.init())
.pipe(concat('app.js'))
.pipe(ngAnnotate())
.pipe(uglify())
.pipe(sourcemaps.write())
.pipe(gulp.dest('app.js'))
```

And that seems to work fine for me. It outputs the sourcemaps into the file itself though.

Versions:

```
"browser-sync": "^2.2.4",
    "gulp": "^3.8.6",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.3.4",
    "gulp-ng-annotate": "^0.2.0",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.0",
    "gulp-replace": "^0.4.0",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^1.1.0",
    "gulp-uglify": "^0.3.1",
    "gulp-util": "^2.2.20"
```

Comment: thanks @Phil - I've tried this as well in my sample repo but I still see the same issue. Are you able to share the specific versions you're running?

Comment: @JamesCrowley updated with versions, pretty old though.

Comment: unfortunately this still isn't working. Big ask I know but if you get a chance, can you reproduce the issue using my GitHub repo? We've tested across several machines and versions and see the same bad behaviour - not sure what we're missing.

Comment: `.pipe(sourcemaps.write())` is the key thing here, to make sure the maps are added as *part of the concatenated js*. This works when concatenating code that's been previously transpiled e.g. using Babel.

Answer (score 0):

If anybody has this issue and find this answer:
the reason why this is not working is because you can't "sourcemap" more transformations with one sourcemaps.init() call. This combination is working for me

```
return gulp.src('/scripts/*.js')
            .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
            .pipe(uglify())
            .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
            .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
            .pipe(concat(outputName + '.min.js'))
            .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
            .pipe(gulp.dest(outputPath))
            .on('end', function() { gutil.log('Minified ' + outputName); })
            .on('error', handleError);
```